# Move the anchorpane using ScrollPane in javafx fxml

Tags: scrollpane

In my JAVAFX FXML application i used Scrollpane to move the anchorpane .I paste all controls inside the scrollpane the problem i found that scrollpane cannot scroll child fxml.ScrollPane is working in parent fxml